# Autocomplete text boxes with jQuery.UI

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm trying out jQuery.UI library.Developing web interfaces is very easy with this library.I was referring to the documentation and demo of using auto complete with "Remote JSONP Datasource" [Here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp)

this is the complete code for getting data from a remote source in to a autocomplete text box.

```
$(function() {
        function log( message ) {
            $( "<div/>" ).text( message ).prependTo( "#log" );
            $( "#log" ).attr( "scrollTop", 0 );
        }

        $( "#city" ).autocomplete({
            source: function( request, response ) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "http://ws.geonames.org/searchJSON",
                    dataType: "jsonp",
                    data: {
                        featureClass: "P",
                        style: "full",
                        maxRows: 12,
                        name_startsWith: request.term
                    },
                    success: function( data ) {
                        response( $.map( data.geonames, function( item ) {
                            return {
                                label: item.name + (item.adminName1 ? ", " + item.adminName1 : "") + ", " + item.countryName,
                                value: item.name
                            }
                        }));
                    }
                });
            },
            minLength: 2,
            select: function( event, ui ) {
                log( ui.item ?
                    "Selected: " + ui.item.label :
                    "Nothing selected, input was " + this.value);
            },
            open: function() {
                $( this ).removeClass( "ui-corner-all" ).addClass( "ui-corner-top" );
            },
            close: function() {
                $( this ).removeClass( "ui-corner-top" ).addClass( "ui-corner-all" );
            }
        });
    });
```

I want to know what is the exact functionality of the following code segment.

```
success: function( data ) { 
    response( $.map( data.geonames, function( item ) {
       return {
        label: item.name + (item.adminName1 ? ", " + item.adminName1 : "") + ", " + item.countryName,
        value: item.name
        }
    }));
}
```

Specially of

> $.map( data.geonames, function( item )

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is an interesting piece of code.

The widget expects an array of objects where each object has properties `label` and/or `value`. What that code is attempting to create is an array that looks like that.

So the call to [`$.map`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map) (which is a pretty useful utility function) is transforming the array of objects retrieved from the JSONP call into an array of objects in the format described above.

One way to read this:

```
$.map( data.geonames, function( item ) {
       return {
        label: item.name + (item.adminName1 ? ", " + item.adminName1 : "") + ", " + item.countryName,
        value: item.name
}
```

would be: **"Create a new array by taking each element of the `data.geonames` array and transforming the element using the given function"**

In this case, the function just builds up an object with a `label` and `value` property so that it will work with the autocomplete widget.

Then, that new array is immediately passed as an argument to the `response` function.